# Terminology of "linear", "quadratic", etc. for multi-input functions

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, quadratics

It is my understanding that, according to typical math terminology:

- The function $f(x, y) = x + y$ is "linear".
  Specifically, it's *linear in both $x$ and $y$*, but this is understood implicitly.
- The function $g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is "quadratic".
  Specifically, it's *quadratic in both $x$ and $y$*, but this is understood implicitly.

But what's $h(x, y) = x \times y$?
Is it correct to call it "linear"? Is it correct to call it "quadratic"?

It seems to me that $h$ is "linear" if $x$ and $y$ are independent, or "quadratic" if $x = y$.
So I'm not sure what I'm supposed to call it. Is there a standard terminology for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $h(x, y) = xy$ is called "bilinear". It is a special case of a quadratic function which, when considered as a function of one variable at a time, is linear.

Comment: Since you said it's a special case of the quadratic, does that mean it's OK (although possibly not as precise as possible) to also call it "quadratic"?

Comment: Yes, I think anything of the form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ can be called quadratic. But it is often good to be more specific.